# Reading xlsx file using SmartXLS

Tags: xlsx, smartxls

Can anybody please tell me how to use SmartXLS to read xlsx file by giving an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    WorkBook workBook = new WorkBook();
    workBook.readXLSX("test.xlsx");
```